# How to use virtual class in cuda?

Tags: c++, cuda

I wrote a simple cuda code to test if I can copy a vector of pointers to classes the GPU.

***This is what I have:***

***test.hpp:***

```
class Class {
public:
    Class() {};
    virtual ~Class() {};

    __host__ __device__ int print() { return 42; };
    __host__ __device__ virtual int getClass() const = 0;
};                                                                                                                                                                                       

class AlphaClass : public Class
{
public:
    AlphaClass() {
      className = "Alpha";
      classAvgGrade = 90;
      classSize = 100;
      for(int i = 0; i < classSize; i++){
          classScores.push_back((90+i)%100);
      } 
    };
    ~AlphaClass() { };

    std::string className;
    int classAvgGrade;
    int classSize; 
    std::vector<int> classScores;

    __host__ __device__ void incClassSize(){
        classSize++;
    };

    __host__ __device__ virtual int getClass() const{
        return 0;
    }; 
};  


class BetaClass : public Class
{                                                                                                                                                                                        
public:
    BetaClass() {
      className = "Beta";
      classAvgGrade = 80;
      classSize = 120;
      for(int i = 0; i < classSize; i++){
          classScores.push_back((80+i)%100);
      } 
    }
    ~BetaClass() { };
    std::string className;
    int classAvgGrade;
    int classSize;
    std::vector<int> classScores;
    
    __host__ __device__ void incClassSize(){
        classSize++;
    }   

    __host__ __device__ virtual int getClass() const{
        return 1;
    };

};
    
    
class CudaClass : public Class
{     
public:
    CudaClass() {
      className = "Cuda";
      classAvgGrade = 70;
      classSize = 110;
      for(int i = 0; i < classSize; i++){
          classScores.push_back(70);
      }   
    };
    ~CudaClass() {
        //do nothing
    };
    
    std::string className;
    int classAvgGrade;
    int classSize;
    std::vector<int> classScores;
    
    __host__ __device__ void incClassSize(){
        classSize++;
    };
 };
```

***test.cpp:***

```
struct GlobalConstants {
    Class** classList;
};  

__constant__ GlobalConstants cuConstRaytracerParams;


   __global__ void useClass()
  {

    Class** deviceClassList = cuConstRaytracerParams.classList;
    AlphaClass* alpha = (AlphaClass*) deviceClassList[0];
    BetaClass* beta = (BetaClass*) deviceClassList[1];
    CudaClass* cuda = (CudaClass*) deviceClassList[2];

    printf("%s\n", alpha->className);
    printf("%s\n", beta->className); 
    printf("%s\n", cuda->ClassName);

    printf("alpha avg = %d\n", alpha->classAvgGrade);
    printf("beta avg = %d\n", beta->classAvgGrade);
    printf("cuda avg = %d\n", cuda->classAvgGrade);

  };  


...

  

    AlphaClass *alpha;
    alpha = new AlphaClass();
    BetaClass *beta;
    beta = new BetaClass();
    CudaClass *cuda;
    cuda = new CudaClass();
    std::vector<Class*> classes;
    classes.push_back(alpha);
    classes.push_back(beta);
    classes.push_back(cuda);
    
    AlphaClass* alpha_ptr;
    BetaClass* beta_ptr;
    CudaClass* cuda_ptr;
        
    // copy classes to cuda
    thrust::device_vector<Class*> deviceClassList;
    for(int i = 0; i < classes.size(); i++){
        if(classes[i]->getClass() == 0){
            cudaMalloc(&alpha_ptr, sizeof(AlphaClass));
            cudaMemcpy(alpha_ptr, &classes[i],sizeof(AlphaClass), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            deviceClassList.push_back(alpha_ptr);

        }else if(classes[i]->getClass() == 1){
            cudaMalloc(&beta_ptr, sizeof(BetaClass));
            cudaMemcpy(beta_ptr, &classes[i],sizeof(BetaClass), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            deviceClassList.push_back(beta_ptr);

            
        }else if(classes[i]->getClass() == 2){
            cudaMalloc(&cuda_ptr, sizeof(CudaClass));
            cudaMemcpy(cuda_ptr, &classes[i],sizeof(CudaClass), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
            deviceClassList.push_back(cuda_ptr);

        }else{
            //do nothing
        }
    }
    Class** class_ptr = thrust::raw_pointer_cast(&deviceClassList[0]);
          
    //ADD IT TO CUDA PARAM STRUCT
    GlobalConstants params;
    params.classList = class_ptr;
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(cuConstRaytracerParams, &params, sizeof(GlobalConstants));

    useClass<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    ...cleanup code
```

**When i run this i don't get the correct value and get the following results:**

> alpha avg = 39696816
>
> beta avg = 70
>
> cuda avg = 0

And i don't get any results for string.

Comment: cast your pointer to Class* ?

Comment: @Ashalynd sure that would get rid of compiler error, but i want to use it as AlphaClass since AlphaClass has data

Comment: The error is not related to cuda: You try to assign a pointer of `Class` to a pointer of `AlphaClass`. To resolve this error you should cast: `AlphaClass* alpha = (AlphaClass*)deviceClassList[0];` However, I think what you are trying to do is not supported. A [mcve] would help to clarify what you want to do.

Comment: To answer you questions: There is a way to use virtual classes, but there are limitations, see this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12704054/5085250) and the [cuda programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#virtual-functions). What do you mean with "copy separately"? Even in you example you are copying separately.

Comment: @havogt copy separately as in I'll have AlphaClass vector, BetaClass vector, and CudaClass vector for each subclass

Comment: Do you want to use all the different `Class`es in one kernel invocation. Or run a kernel for each of the `Class`es? In the latter case I would recommend to pass the `Class` as an argument (using templates).

Comment: @havogt all classes in one kernel call

Comment: Is putting the different pointers in a `struct` and passing the `struct` to the kernel an option?

Comment: @havogt that would be the last resort. But I would prefer using a vector since I can add/delete different classes flexibly

Comment: There are still other problems in the code that you probably should solve first. For example, you cannot use std::string and std::vector in device code. Maybe this will change you design decisions.

Comment: What is the purpose of these `Class`es? In you example there seems to be no need to use subclasses. They all have the same variables and functions...

Comment: @havogt well this is a simplified version of what i'm working on. the actual code is way more complicated and i wanted to verify if i could use this general format to copy info to the device.

Comment: Yes, of course... But I would say it is not simplified enough. There is a lot of stuff in your code that is not needed to demonstrate the behaviour. Therefore, it is not easy to get it at a glance. Additionally, the error that you posted was not related to the main problem. That's why I asked for a [mcve].

Comment: I've changed the code so there are no pointer errors whatsoever. But i have a different problem: firstly, i can't print string like you've said. I'm not sure how to fix that. Secondly, I still don't get the correct values for classAvgGrade for each class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The OP raises several questions. The main question is in the title "How to use virtual class in cuda?". An unrelated question is how to use strings in cuda code. I will focus mainly on the question in the title.

According to the [cuda c programming guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#virtual-functions) you can use virtual functions but with limitations. The limitation you run into is

> It is not allowed to pass as an argument to a __global__ function an object of a class derived from virtual base classes.

In your example code you try to avoid this by passing the object (array of device pointers) via constant memory. However I think the programming guide is just not precise here. I think **it is not possible to copy an object of a class derived from virtual base classes to device**. The problem is (as far as I understand) that you will copy the *host* virtual function table to device.

The example code is much too complicated (and has other problems) to demonstrate the behaviour. The following more simplified code shows what you can do with virtual functions in cuda:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class Class
{
public:
    __host__ __device__ virtual int getNumber() = 0;
    __host__ __device__ virtual ~Class() {};
};

class ClassA: public Class
{
public:
    int aNumber;
    __host__ __device__ ClassA(): aNumber(0){}

    __host__ __device__ int getNumber()
    {
        return aNumber;
    }
};

class ClassB: public Class
{
public:
    int aNumber;
    int anotherNumber;
    __host__ __device__ ClassB(): aNumber(1), anotherNumber(2){}

    __host__ __device__ int getNumber()
    {
        return aNumber;
    }
};

__global__ void invalidClassKernel( Class* superClass )
{
    printf( "superClass->getNumber(): %d\n", superClass->getNumber() );
}

__global__ void validClassKernel()
{
    Class* classVector[2];
    classVector[0] = new ClassA();
    classVector[1] = new ClassB();

    printf( "classVector[0]->getNumber(): %d\n", classVector[0]->getNumber() );
    printf( "classVector[1]->getNumber(): %d\n", classVector[1]->getNumber() );

    delete classVector[0];
    delete classVector[1];
}

int main()
{
    ClassA hostClassA;
    ClassB hostClassB;

    ClassA* devClassA;
    ClassA* devClassB;
    cudaMalloc( &devClassA, sizeof(ClassA) );
    cudaMalloc( &devClassB, sizeof(ClassB) );
    cudaMemcpy( devClassA, &hostClassA, sizeof( ClassA ), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );
    cudaMemcpy( devClassB, &hostClassB, sizeof( ClassB ), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice );

    validClassKernel<<<1,1>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    cudaError_t error = cudaGetLastError();
    if(error!=cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: validClassKernel: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error) );
    }

    invalidClassKernel<<<1,1>>>( devClassA );
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
    error = cudaGetLastError();
    if(error!=cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr,"ERROR: invalidClassKernel: %s\n", cudaGetErrorString(error) );
    }
}
```

The `validClassKernel()` shows how you can store pointers of derived objects in an array of base class pointers and access the virtual function `getNumber()`. In this example the objects are created in device code.

The `invalidClassKernel()` shows that you cannot use in device code a copy of an object derived from a virtual base class that was created on the host. The code compiles but the kernel fails with `an illegal memory access was encountered`. Very likely this is the main problem in the original example code.

---

Other problems:

- You cannot use std::string in device code, see this question [Can we use the string data type in C++ within kernels](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9910739/5085250). As a solution you could use a `char` array of constant size. The same applies to std::vector (`classScores`).